# Prolog, how should I construct a list of list to a single list?

Tags: prolog

I want to construct a list of list to interleave each other to a single list like: coon([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]], X) should return X=1,2,3,4,5,6. and there is a condition that each sublist should only have the same length, otherwise, it should fail such as [[q,r,y],[a,e],[c,g,t],X] shouid fail, and coon([A,B,C],[q,w,e,r,t,y]) should only return one solution, that is A=[q,r],B=[w,t],C=[e,y]. 
my recent approach is.

```
  conns([],[]).
  conns([[Head|Tail]|X],[Head|Y]):-
    append(X,[Tail],X2),
    conns(X2,Y).                                                

conns([[]|T],A):-
    conns(T,A).
```

It gives me multiple solutions when I try coon([A,B,C],[q,w,e,r,t,y]).
I have been trying hours to figure it out but all failed. How should I return the single list to each sub-lists that contain the same length?
Thank you so much!

Comment: is this for the artificial intelligence class?

Comment: Nope, the AI is far away for me.

Comment: Hint: what do you think `append(Head,[Tail],X2)` will do? What is its function here? What is `H` doing in that clause?

Comment: Thank you for notifying me that, I just typed wrong for my variables, but it still doesn't change the result I prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is with this predicate clause:

```
conns([[]|T],A):-
    conns(T,A).
```

This allows solutions more general than you are wanting to define. Specifically, if I understand the problem correctly, the first argument to `conns` should always be a list whose elements are lists all of equal length. That would mean that if `[[]|T]` is the first argument and you expect `conns([[]|T], A)` to succeed, then `T` should also look like `[[]|R]` or `[]`. That is, it should be a (possibly empty) list of empty lists.

If you revise the empty list case according to this constraint, your solution will work:

```
% The case where the first argument consists of non-empty lists    
conns([[Head|Tail]|X], [Head|Y]):-
    append(X, [Tail], X2),
    conns(X2, Y).

% Base case in which first argument is a list of empty lists
conns([], []).
conns([[]|T], []) :-
    conns(T, []).
```

Now when you run the query, you get this:

```
| ?- conns([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]], R).

R = [1,2,3,4,5,6] ? ;

no
| ?-
```

As well as:

```
| ?-  conns([A,B,C], [q,w,e,r,t,y]).

A = [q,r]
B = [w,t]
C = [e,y] ? a

no
| ?-
```

This solution does leave a choice point, which I'll leave as an exercise to eliminate if you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works! I have a question, why should add base case conns([[]],[]), the first argument as the empty list of empty list?can I just write it as conns([],[]).?

Comment: @YiJustin actually you are correct: you can, and perhaps should depending upon your desired solution set, use `conns([], [])` in this case. The only difference is that using `conn([]., [])` will accept an empty list as a solution, whereas using `conns([[]], [])` will accept down to a single element but not an empty list, keeping in mind that `[]` (an empty list) and `[[]]` (a list with one element) are not the same thing. If you are happy with my answer, please click the Accept answer check mark next to the answer. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `conns([[a],[]],Xs).` incorrectly succeeds, thats not what you asked for, @YiJu

Answer (score 5):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd),[transpose/2]).

connsx(Xss, Xs) :-
   transpose(Xss, XssT),
   append(XssT, Xs).
```

Comment: This program still can be improved w.r.t. termination! In particular the second argument has currently no influence on termination.